# Evaluating whether a company is trading below cash...?

Tags: stock-analysis, stock-valuation

I'm trying to evaluate the stock $GEO...specifically if their trading below cash at the moment.

*All figures sourced from Yahoo Finance

Their total cash is 48.72 M and Total Debt is 1.99 Bn while their Market cap is at 1.12 Bn.

To find if their trading below cash value, wouldn't you subtract their cash by their liabilities and they see if its below their market cap?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is what is meant by "trading below cash".  It means that investors think the company is burning cash to the point that it cannot pay its debts (the company is not even worth it's residual cash value if it were to pay off all debt immediately).

Note that in your example, GEO is by no means trading below cash, since cash minus debts is *negative* 1.94 Bn and it's trading at *positive* 1.12 Bn.

It's very common for companies to have less cash than debt, so "trading below cash" is quite rare and is usually a sign of trouble.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the feedback. It's not ideal but I read that sometimes its an indicator of a value investment opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See [here](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tradingbelowcash.asp):

> The financial term trading below cash refers to when a company's total share value is less than its cash minus debts.

In this case, you have 48.72M cash and 1.99B debt, leaving negative 1.95B residual value. The market cap is positive 1.2B, so it's not at all below cash.

That said, having so little cash compared to the debt seems very risky, and unless the company expects significant positive cash flow soon I'd probably stay away.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the feedback. I was looking to find any stocks trading below cash for value investment opportunities.